# why my loop keeps repeating after I entered the input of the program correctly

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am having problems with my code. I have entered the correct input but the program keeps running. I think I declared it incorrectly but I don't know which part it is. How am I supposed to initialize it?

my program is about seat reservations. and my objective is to mark 'X' based on the input of the user. and If that seat is already taken, I need to prompt a question to ask them if they want to input a seat again, and if not I will direct them to the main menu and their reservation will be canceled.

output that i did:

```
Enter your seat number: (EX: 1A)1a
Invalid option!
Enter your seat number: (EX: 1A)1A

Enter your seat number: (EX: 1A)
```

here is the some part of my program

```
#define ROWS 11
#define COLS 8
#define PASSENGERSIZE sizeof(passenger)

typedef struct{
    char city[20], name[50], seatcol;
    int age, seatrow, id;

}passenger;

char seat[ROWS][COLS];

int selection;
int seatavailable=60;
int i,j,x,k;
char answer, Y ;
int status=0;


void chooseseat(){
    passenger p;
   do{
    printf("\n\t\t\tEnter your seat number: (EX: 1A)");
    scanf("%d%c",&p.seatrow, &p.seatcol);

    if(p.seatrow == 1 && p.seatcol == 'A'){
        seat[0][0]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 1 && p.seatcol == 'B'){
        seat[0][2]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 1 && p.seatcol == 'C'){
        seat[0][2]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 1 && p.seatcol == 'D'){
        seat[0][3]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 1 && p.seatcol == 'E'){
        seat[0][4]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 1 && p.seatcol == 'F'){
        seat[0][5]= 'X';}
    //2
.........

    //10
    else if(p.seatrow == 10 && p.seatcol == 'A'){
        seat[9][0]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 10 && p.seatcol == 'B'){
        seat[9][2]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 10 && p.seatcol == 'C'){
        seat[9][2]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 10 && p.seatcol == 'D'){
        seat[9][3]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 10 && p.seatcol == 'E'){
        seat[9][4]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 10 && p.seatcol == 'F'){
        seat[9][5]= 'X';}

    else{
        printf("Invalid option!");
        p.id--;
        getch();
    } 
    p.id++;

    status = (p.seatrow && p.seatcol != seat[ROWS][COLS]);

    }while(status);

    if(!status){
        printf("\n\t\t Already allocate seat. Choose another seat? (Y/N)");
        scanf("%c", answer);

        if(answer == 'Y'){
        chooseseat();
        }
        else{
            printf("Your data will be not saved and will be returned to main menu:");
            main();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This whole `if/else` spaghetti could be replaced by a single `seat[p.seatrow - 1][p.seatcol - 'A'] = 'X';` (well, plus some sanity checking perhaps)

Comment: `scanf("%c", answer);` --> `scanf(" %c", &answer);` Notice a space before `%c` and an ampersand before `answer`

Comment: @EugeneSh. how can I replace it? what do I need to use?

Comment: @DavidRanieri, thank you. I'll take note of that

Comment: Exactly what I wrote. BTW, you have a mistake as you write to `[0][2]` for both `B` and `C`

Comment: You were [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73019451/how-to-call-the-input-from-the-user#comment128966871_73019451) about the use of `scanf` and `%c` in your [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73019451/how-to-call-the-input-from-the-user). Don't just make a note: change the code right now. Turn up the compiler warnings too - they would tell you about the missing `&`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `status = (p.seatrow && p.seatcol != seat[ROWS][COLS]);`? p.seatcol should be a letter A..F. `seat[ROWS][COLS]` accesses an element well beyond this array. Btw, seat[][] ist set to 'X', which will be compared against A..F

Comment: @user5329483 I used ```status = (p.seatrow && p.seatcol != seat[ROWS][COLS]);``` to declare that the user input is not equal to the array so I can declare it in the next loop. because i want to prompt that input is already taken, and will ask them to input another input again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWS 11
#define COLS 8

typedef struct
{
    char city[20], name[50], seatcol;
    int age, seatrow, id;
} passenger;

int seat[ROWS][COLS]; //0=available, >1: passenger number

void chooseSeat(int PassengerNumber)
{
    passenger p;
    for(;;)
    {
        unsigned SeatRowIndex;  //0=1st, 1=2nd, ...
        unsigned SeatColIndex;  //0=A, 1=B, ...
        int ParsedValues;
        printf("\n\t\t\tEnter seat number for passenger %d: (EX: 1A)", PassengerNumber);

        ParsedValues=scanf("%d%c", &p.seatrow, &p.seatcol);

        SeatColIndex = toupper(p.seatcol)-'A'; //no matter if seat 1a or 1A, just get it 0-based
        SeatRowIndex = p.seatrow - 1; //get it 0-based

        if (ParsedValues==2 && SeatRowIndex<ROWS && SeatColIndex<COLS)
        {
            /***legal seat given.***/
            if (seat[SeatRowIndex][SeatColIndex])
            {
                printf("\n\t\t Seat %d%c already allocated by passenger %d. Choose another seat? (Y/N)", p.seatrow, p.seatcol, seat[SeatRowIndex][SeatColIndex]);
                for(;;) //until valid answer given
                {
                    switch(toupper(getchar()))
                    {
                        case 'Y':
                            break;
                        case 'N':
                            printf("Passenger %d will have no seat.", PassengerNumber);
                            return;
                        default: //invalid answer
                            continue;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                continue;
            }
            seat[SeatRowIndex][SeatColIndex] = PassengerNumber; //now occupied
            return; //done.
        }
        printf("Seat %d%c not exist!", p.seatrow, p.seatcol);
    }
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char ** /*argv*/)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<5; i++)
        chooseSeat(i);

    int col;
    printf("\n\n SEAT MAP\n   ");
    for(col=0; col<COLS; col++) //print ruler
        putchar(col+'A');

    for (i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        printf ("\n%2d ", i+1);
        for(col=0; col<COLS; col++)
            putchar(seat[i][col] ? 'X' : '.');
    }
    puts("\nDone.");
    return 0;
}
```