# how can I declare that the seat is already taken in if else statement

Tags: c, if-statement

I have taken all of your comments, and I am still unsure about it but am I doing it properly? And do I need to use for loop to replace if/else-if statements?

```
if(p.seatrow > ROWS || p.seatcol > COLS)
{     
      printf("Invalid option!");     
           chooseseat();

} else if (seat[p.seatrow-1][p.seatcol-'A'] != 'X')
{       printf("\n\t\t Seat is already reserved. Choose another seat? (Y/N)");        
        scanf("%c", answer);    
        if(answer == 'Y')
        {         
              chooseseat();         
        }
else{             
        printf("Your data will be not saved and will be returned to main menu:");             
         
               main();       
      } 

}else if if (seat[p.seatrow-1][p.seatcol-'A'] != 'X'){ 
          printf("Congratulations. Your seat number is %d%c",p.seatrow,p.seatcol); 
}
```

I am still working with the same program and still facing issues. I want to have an else-if statement where I can say that the input of the user is already taken. I want to say that the seat that they entered is already taken, but the problem is I don't know what variable or condition should I use for it.

```
#define ROWS 11
#define COLS 8
#define PASSENGERSIZE sizeof(passenger)

typedef struct{
    char city[20], name[50], seatcol;
    int age, seatrow, id;

}passenger;

char seat[ROWS][COLS];

int selection;
int seatavailable=60;
int i,j,x,k;
char answer, Y ;
int status=0;


void chooseseat(){
    passenger p;
   
    printf("\n\t\t\tEnter your seat number: (EX: 1A)");
    scanf(" %d%c",&p.seatrow, &p.seatcol);

    if(p.seatrow == 1 && p.seatcol == 'A'){
        seat[0][0]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 1 && p.seatcol == 'B'){
        seat[0][1]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 1 && p.seatcol == 'C'){
        seat[0][2]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 1 && p.seatcol == 'D'){
        seat[0][3]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 1 && p.seatcol == 'E'){
        seat[0][4]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 1 && p.seatcol == 'F'){
        seat[0][5]= 'X';}
.....
    //10
    else if(p.seatrow == 10 && p.seatcol == 'A'){
        seat[9][0]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 10 && p.seatcol == 'B'){
        seat[9][1]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 10 && p.seatcol == 'C'){
        seat[9][2]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 10 && p.seatcol == 'D'){
        seat[9][3]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 10 && p.seatcol == 'E'){
        seat[9][4]= 'X';}
    else if(p.seatrow == 10 && p.seatcol == 'F'){
        seat[9][5]= 'X';}

/* In this part, I want to declare that the seat entered is already taken. */

    else if(seat[p.seatrow][p.seatcol] != 'X'){

      printf("\n\t\t Seat is already reserved. Choose another seat? (Y/N)");
        scanf(" %c", &answer);

        if(answer == 'Y'){
        chooseseat();
        }
        else{
            printf("Your data will be not saved and will be returned to main menu:");
            main();
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Invalid option!");
    } 
    printf("Congratulations. Your seat number is %d%c",p.seatrow,p.seatcol);
```

Comment: Oh dear, those `if` trees can be replaced by `seat[p.seatrow-1][p.seatcol-'A']= 'X';` can't they? Please shrink your code fragment by doing that. Then make sure it is more of a [mre]. Then writing an answer will be much easier.

Comment: No sure what is your question. To init memory you can use memset. To avoid your else if nightmare of copy paste, you can try something like `seat[p.seatrow - 1][p.seatcol - 'A']`

Comment: As written you are trying to check whether the seat is taken *after* you assigned the value `'X'` to it - in other words it will definitely be taken at that point

Comment: you need to check if an `'X'` lives at the `seat` index before assigning it.

Comment: It seems to me you are doing it backward. You would want to check the array entry being set to 'X' before you set it. You should also convert `p.seatrow` and `p.seatcol` to indexes first to avoid all those if statements. And of course you would want to validate that the row and column indexes are valid before using them. And you should be checking the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: @Yunnosch See the first comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026844/why-my-loop-keeps-repeating-after-i-entered-the-input-of-the-program-correctly) :) But the OP seem to be ignoring advices.

Comment: That is actually a duplicate, isn't it? @EugeneSh. I do not see a difference. gwen, please explain what the difference is and why you did not take the feedback there and make understanding and answering your question here (if it IS different) unnecessarily hard.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am sorry, I am trying to apply what you said but I don't have an Idea to declare them and I only knew that method. And do I have to do it like this repeatedly or am I doing it wrong?

``` seat[p.seatrow-1][p.seatcol-'A']= 'X';
 seat[p.seatrow-1][p.seatcol-'B']= 'X';```

Comment: You need to replace this whole `if/else if` ladder with a isngle line `seat[p.seatrow-1][p.seatcol-'A']= 'X';`. But checking if the seat is taken needs to be done *before* that, like `if (seat[p.seatrow-1][p.seatcol-'A'] != 'X') ...`

Comment: And be sure to initialize the `seat` array to something other than 'X' values.

Comment: what if you have 100 rows by 1000 columns?

Comment: am I doing it right?

Comment: Do I need to use for loop if I need to replace those if/else if statements?

Comment: oh my, please edit your question and put your formatted code there before everyone's eyes explode

Comment: @yano I'm sorry, I already updated it, and am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I think your code needs restructuring. You need to check if the seat is empty before doing anything else. Also "main" is entry point of program in C, it is better not to use it for other purposes.

As described in the comments, instead of using if-else statement for assignment it is better to use the following:

```
seat[p.seatrow - 1][p.seatcol - 'A'] = ...
```

Considering all of these, the following code will do the job you want.

First, it asks about user input, then it checks if it is in valid range of inputs. After that, it checks if the seat is already taken or not.
If the seat was empty it reserves it and quits the function. If any of the above steps fails, it asks for user input again.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define ROWS 11
#define COLS 8
#define PASSENGERSIZE sizeof(passenger)

typedef struct{
    char city[20], name[50], seatcol;
    int age, seatrow, id;
}passenger;

char seat[ROWS][COLS]={0};
int selection;
int seatavailable=60;
int i,j,x,k;
char answer, Y ;
int status=0;

void chooseseat(){
    passenger p;
    // Read the user input until it reserves a seat or request quitting.
    while (true){
        // Read user input.
        printf("\nEnter your seat number: (EX: 1A)");
        scanf(" %d%c",&p.seatrow, &p.seatcol);

        // Check if the seat requested is valid entry.
        if (p.seatrow > 0 && p.seatrow <= ROWS &&
            p.seatcol >= 'A' && p.seatcol <= 'A' + COLS){

                // Input range is valid, check if seat is already taken.
                if (seat[p.seatrow - 1][p.seatcol - 'A'] != 'X'){
                    // Seat is available, reserve it and break the loop.
                    seat[p.seatrow - 1][p.seatcol - 'A'] = 'X';
                    printf("Congratulations. Your seat number is %d%c\n",p.seatrow,p.seatcol);
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    // Seat is already taken.
                    printf("Seat is already taken\n.");
                }
        }
        else{
            // Input range is invalid.
            printf("Invalid seat row/col,\n");
        }
        // Ask user if he wants to continue.
        printf("\nChoose another seat? (Y/N)");
        scanf(" %c", &answer);
        if (answer != 'Y'){
             printf("Your data will be not saved and will be returned to main menu.\n");
             break;
        }
    }
}


int main() {
   chooseseat();
   return 0;
}
```